# Running services 'Google Play Services' uses alot of RAM

Tags: java, android, memory-management, admob

I made a mediaplayer in Android Studio which uses a Service to control playback.

I compared the ram usage with a mp3 player from the store and i noticed most mediaplayers stay below 200mb memory usage.

Mine also stays below 200mb memory but for some reason sometimes **'Google Play Services'** shows up in the process list almost exceeding 100mb.

(**Settings-> Developer options -> Running services -> My App**)

**'Google Play Services'** uses **97mb** and i'm not sure why this shows up.

**P.S**
I'm using **Admob banners** in my app so maybe that's the cause? Because i read somewhere banner ads are memory eaters.

Comment: Have you tried using Android Profiler in Studio? You can take heap dumps and analyze the objects for leaks.

Comment: Since I implemented ads in my app I have the same problem. The app is closed, but a foreground service is running. My app uses now more than double the RAM than before. Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: anyone find the solution?